# Lemma 8.1 Munkres matrix norm inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]This is probably a bad question but,
[image: Munkres Analysis on Manifolds pg. 84]

why do we need $n$? If $|E^{-1}|$ is the operator norm then shouldn't we just be able to take $n =1$? Again, I'm probably misunderstanding something very simple I apologize in advance. Thank you!

Comment: This needs more context. Please include the full proof.

Comment: Yes, the operator norm works out nicely, and you don’t need any prefactors.

Comment: Included the full proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Munkres uses the $\sup$-norm for vectors and matrices. See pages 4 and 5. Doing so he gets Theorem 1.3 which is applied in the proof of Lemma 8.1.